# File.Replace error..how to use?

Tags: vb.net

i am using the following code to copy files from one folder to another...

```
Public Shared Sub CopyFlashScriptFile(ByVal SourceDirectory As String, ByVal DestinationDirectory As String)
        Try
            Dim f() As String = Directory.GetFiles(SourceDirectory)
            For i As Integer = 0 To UBound(f)
                File.Copy(f(i), DestinationDirectory & "\" & System.IO.Path.GetFileName(f(i)))
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

But the the file already exists in the destination folder it throws an error...Can anybody help me with the Replace code??I mean i want the file to be replaced with the new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an overload of the [`Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5.aspx) method that takes a Boolean indicating if it should overwrite:

```
File.Copy(f(i), DestinationDirectory & "\" & System.IO.Path.GetFileName(f(i)), True)
```

---

For what it's worth, you may also want to use [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) to combine paths rather than concating strings.

```
File.Copy(f(i), Path.Combine(DestinationDirectory, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(f(i))), True)
```

This has the advantage of being smart enough to insert a `\` only if it's needed (So you don't end up with paths like `foo\\bar`), and can concat multiple paths using various overloads.

Answer (score 1):

Add `true` at the end to overwrite. ([File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5.aspx#Y88))

```
 File.Copy(f(i), DestinationDirectory & "\" & System.IO.Path.GetFileName(f(i)), True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `File.Copy` method does not have a parameter like `bool Overwrite`, then use

```
if(File.Exists(f(1))) 
  File.Delete();
```

**If has**

```
File.Copy(f(i), DestinationDirectory & "\" & System.IO.Path.GetFileName(f(i)), true);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5.aspx

Use the overload of File.Copy Method (String, String, Boolean)

where boolean will represent for overwriting

Answer (score 0):

There is  an overload to set Overwrite to true.

Best described in the MSDN source [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

look at this line .. why is system.IO.Path.GetFileName in what appears to be quotes

```
File.Copy(f(i), DestinationDirectory & "\" & System.IO.Path.GetFileName
```

change to this

```
File.Copy(f(i), DestinationDirectory & "\\" & System.IO.Path.GetFileName
```

or declare the backslash as a const it will make it easier to read